# HTML/CSS/Javascript Scrollable div won't scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a simple webpage with a paragraph and a textarea inside of a div. When the two elements leave the div I want the user to be able to scroll up/down

My div has overflow set to auto, but when the elements leave the page the user is still not able to scroll

Code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "brdstyle.css" />
    <title>BrD</title>
</head>

<script src = "brdapp.js"></script>

<body>
<div id = "background">
    <div id = "console">
        <p id = "consoletext"></p>
        <textarea rows = "1" id = "textinput" onkeydown = "checkInput();"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#console {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#consoletext {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Monospace;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#textinput {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Monospace;
    width: calc(100% - 22px);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkInput () {
    var event = window.event || event.which;

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addLine(document.getElementById("textinput").value);
        document.getElementById("textinput").value = "";
    }

    var newHeight = ((pageHeight - 20) - document.getElementById("consoletext").style.height);
    if (document.getElementById("textinput").style.height != newHeight) {
        document.getElementById("textinput").style.height = newHeight + "px";
    }
}

function addLine (line) {
    var newText = document.createTextNode(line);
    var newLineElement = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById("consoletext").appendChild(newText);
    document.getElementById("consoletext").appendChild(newLineElement);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-value of overflow tells the browser to automatic "decide" whether the content should be scrollable or not:

```
 overflow-y: auto;
```

If you want a div to "be scrollable" you need to tell your Browser this in your CSS:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the Comments of this Answer here is your solution:

CSS:

```
 * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#console {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#consoletext {
    color: white;
    background-color:black;
    font-family: Monospace;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#textinput {
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Monospace;
    width: calc(100% - 22px);
    overflow: scroll;

}
```

Comment: Ok the scrollbar shows now but the elements go off screen and the scrollbar never becomes active, it's like the browser thinks there is nothing to be scrolled because there are only a few elements.

Comment: look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pdyegy5u/ its because there is no need for the content to be scrollable. if you want the inputfield to be scrollable then you have to set the 'overflow-y: scroll;'  for your input element

Comment: the Elements are not leaving the div in this case. if you show me your content, that cause the elements to leave the div then i could better understand your problem

Comment: I want the div to scroll if the text in textarea or paragraph goes off the screen

Comment: ah so what you want is that your div has a fixed height, like your textarea, and if one of the elements goes off the screen through much input of the user (or whatever) then your Container (div) should be scrollable that you can see the "off screen content"? if this is the case. this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/fjq3sLLf/

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and defining the height of the div fixed everything. Please rewrite your comment into an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: I've edited this Answer instead of ading onother Post (stackoverflow told me to do so :) )